# Can AWS Cognito work with both on-premises SAML IdP and social medial accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

we have a on-premises SAML IdP which stores our customer information. Now we are considering moving onto AWS cloud. Question is can we use AWS Cognito to allow customers authenticated with their existing credentials against our on-premises SAML IdP while in the meantime allow them to log with social media account such as Google or Facebook?

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html